# A Responsive Design Image Won't Scale as Window Resizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im working on converting an existing site to a RWD but have been struggling with the header image. Following this tutorial (among others on the www) http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images

I can't get the header image on this (or any) page to respond appropriately when scaling to below 480px
http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/dirt-bikes-for-sale.html

I have tried everything I can think of or read but the darned image won't display properly.

If anyone wouldn't mind sharing with me what I'm missing, I'd be most appreciative and I thank each and everyone of you in advance.

Below is a snippet from the main css file and the entire mobile.css file which is called with a media query when a pages is scaled to below 480px

```css
img {max-width:100%}

    #PageWrapper{ 
    width:960px;
    border:5px groove #DDDDDD;
    margin:15px auto;
    background-image:url(../image-files/background.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#Header {
    color:#ffffff;
    position:relative;
    height:118px;
    background-image:url(../image-files/motocross-ruts.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;   
}

#Header a.header-home-link{width:960px;height:118px;display:block;}

#ContentWrapper{float:left;width:100%;}

#ContentColumn{margin:0 180px;}

#NavColumn{float:left;width:179px;margin-left:-965px;}

#ExtraColumn{float:left;width:179px;margin-left:-180px;}

#Footer{clear:both;width:100%;padding:8px 0;height:180px;border-top:3px groove #656565;}

#Footer .Liner{margin:20px;padding:0;}

The following is the mobile.css file

    body {font-size:80%;}

.Liner{padding:2px;}

#PageWrapper{max-width:480px; margin:10px;}

#Header {min-height:39px;}

#Header a.header-home-link{display:none;}

#NavColumn{display:none;}

#ExtraColumn{display:none;}

#ContentWrapper{max-width:100%;background-image:url(../image-files/mobile320-background.gif);background-repeat:repeat-y;}

#ContentColumn{max-width:100%; margin:0;}

#ExtraNavTop {display:none;}

.Navigation{display:none;}

.mostPopular {display:none;}
```

I have been modifying these two files all day and have seen a plethora of different configurations. Just not the one I want which would be an appropriately scaled image. This way I can move on to the growing list of to-do's related to this RWD conversion.

Stuart K

Comment: Wasn't me, but probably because your question is very general, and you didn't post and code for what you've tried.

Comment: My Bad...I figured anyone looking at this post would just view:source the page to see the current and exact css. I'll edeit my initial post to include the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least two places where you have fixed widths

```
#Header a.header-home-link
```

and

```
#PageWrapper
```

Both a width of 960px and no max-width set - therefore your page is never going to get any smaller in width than 960px - if the browser window is any smaller, you'll just get a horizontal scrollbar on the body.

In addition, as others have pointed out, your header image is not an img tag - it is a background image - and therefore won't respond to img { max-width: 100%; }. You must use `background-size`, there are several values that you can use such as `cover`, `contain`, a percentage, etc.

Look them up on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size - and try them out to find out which one works for you.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate everyone's input on this. I'm a bit overwhelemed so it's gonna take me a little bit to digest all of this

Comment: I would be overwhelmed - converting all those floats and negative margins to a responsive design is going to be a mess. To be honest, I'd rewrite the HTML/CSS to build that page from scratch (at least the main containing elements whose code you posted). Doing it that way will probably be just as easy, if not easier, to convert it to a  responsive design rather than hacking the nasty CSS that is already in place.

Comment: I agree with you here Adam, The CSS IS a mess but it's a LOT better than in the past. I've been working my tail off to clean up my earliest and most novice mistakes

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. Could you sprinkle a few more clues my direction? BTW, I found: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp  to be a little more readable

Comment: or BoJangles, If either of you could assist me I'd be most appreciative. I have been working on correcting my negative margins etc but am having trouble. Why are both columns getting pushed down like can be seen here: http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/motocross.html If either of you could assist me with this and telling me why I have been blocked from asking any questions I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your CSS #Header, your header image is a background!!! Your header block doesn't contain any `<img>`, there is nothing to scale. Try CSS3 rule `background-size` instead or insert it into the header block with `<img>`.
**CSS from your site** http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/dirt-bikes-for-sale.html:

```
#Header {
    // Here it is!!!
    background-image: url("../image-files/motocross-ruts.jpg");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 118px;
    position: relative;
}
```